# Linked library runs on simulator on xcode but not with react-native run-ios

Tags: react-native

So, on my app i want to use a library called react-native-progress. I've installed it and linked to ios. If i run the app on xcode it works, and shows the progress circle. But if i try to run the app with "react-native run-ios" it says "No component found for view with the name "ARTShape".
I've restarted xcode, my computer, the simulator and nothing seems to help, have you guys seen anything like this? And how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the library linked right and try to link it manually instead

Comment: I've linked it manually, i've made my app from scratch again and everything is working. I still don't know what caused it, but i fixed it now. Thank you for your answer